# Return an instance of union type after spreading it

Tags: javascript, typescript, union-types

I have a general interface which I use to define properties (let's say it's an `Animal`).
Then I have extensions of this interface, which have additional different fields.

I want to define a function that gets an instance of an animal, spreads it - and parses a specific field.
The result value should be the same as the input's; however I get an error, as not all animals are equal :P

How can I use the spread operator and still return the same type?

```js
interface AnimalProps { name: string; size: string; }

class Dog implements AnimalProps {
  name: string;
  size: string;
  bark(): void { console.log(`${this.name} says: 'woof'`); }
  constructor(name: string, size: string) {
    this.name = name;
    this.size = size;
  }
}

class Bird implements AnimalProps {
  name: string;
  size: string;
  fly(): void  { console.log(`${this.name} says: 'I love flying'`); }
  constructor(name: string, size: string) {
    this.name = name;
    this.size = size;
  }
}

type Animal = Dog | Bird;
function addSizeUnits(animal: Animal): Animal {
  // Property 'fly' is missing in type '{ size: string; name: string; }' but required in type 'Bird'.
  return { ...animal, size: `${animal.size} meters` };
}
```

Obviously I'm simplifying the existing (legacy) code here, but the bottom line is that I do need to use `fly` and `bark` and therefore I need the actual union types - and not the basic `Animal`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A generic function should work here. Something like:

```js
function addSizeUnits<T extends Animal>(animal: T) {
  return { ...animal, size: `${animal.size} meters` };
}
```

Note that I removed the return type annotation because the type inference should figure that out for you, but if you want to add it back you can use something like <strike>`T & { size: string }`</strike> correction, just `T` should be fine because you already have `size` in `AnimalProps`.

Answer (score 1):

This can easily be addressed by using a [generic constraint](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints):

```
function addSizeUnits<A extends Animal>(animal: A): A {
  return { ...animal, size: `${animal.size} meters` };
}
```

This ensures that your argument type and your return type are the same type of `Animal`.